# Fill region below stairs plot with a particular transparency using Makie.jl in Julia

Tags: julia, makie.jl

I'd like to fill the region below a `stairs!()` plot (between the stairs and the x axis) in order to get something like the gray area in the image, but with a specific % transparency.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat hacky way (digs into the stair plot to get the graphed points):

```
function stairpts(s)
    pts = s.plots[1].converted[1][]
    [p[1] for p in pts], [p[2] for p in pts]
end

s = stairs!(xs, ys, step=:post)

xs′, ys′ = stairpts(s)
band!(xs′, 0*ys′, ys′, color=(s.color, 0.25)) # 0.25 alpha
```

Creating a [recipe](https://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/documentation/recipes/) for this
type of plot is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

What you show looks like multiple barplots or histograms (`hist!()` function or `barplot!()` function) with transparency allowing see-through overlap. Could you do this using `barplot` or `hist!` (depending on your data) instead of `stairs!`? If you want the barplots to be more uniform in outline, you could make the outline `strokewidth` thicker and the same `strokecolor` as the bars.

Comment: I'm not sure if a histogram or a barplot would work. Well, I guess the "bars" having the same width doesn't help. I'll change the graph.